# How to find and update columns containing a superscript character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using a SQL Server database. In a specific column, in some cells (which are of type `varchar`), there is this character : `³`

I don't know how to find cells containing this character, and replace this character with character `j`.

When I use this query to find cells :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE col LIKE '%³%'
```

I get regular `3`'s as well.

Can you tell me how to do these? I looked up in the internet but I couldn't find what I want. Thanks.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET col = REPLACE(col, N'³', 'j') WHERE CHARINDEX(col, N'³') > 0`

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is:

```
UPDATE table
SET col = replace(col, N'³', 'j');
```

You don't need to search for the rows before updating / replacing the values, so no need for a `SELECT`. All you need to do is `UPDATE`.

If you want to add more conditions to filter your rows and only update some, you can just use a `WHERE` clause and specify more filters.

```
UPDATE table
SET col = replace(col, N'³', 'j');
WHERE col NOT LIKE '%..%'
    AND col2 ...
    AND col3 ...
etc.
```

You can use the same `WHERE` clause in a simple `SELECT` to see what rows will get updated before running the `UPDATE`.

In order not to go over all of the rows and to make your query faster, you can add a WHERE clause to update only the rows which contain that character.

**EDIT/UPDATE (final):**

In order to detect if data is uppercase / superscript you need to use collation:

```
UPDATE @t
SET col = replace(col, NCHAR(179) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, 'j');
```

Comment: Is this ok too? `UPDATE table
SET col = replace(col, '³', 'ij');`

Comment: this is could have been made a comment but still +1

Comment: Does this answer the question how to find only rows with `³` instead also which contain `3`?

Comment: @jason Yes, that's ok too. You can replace one or more characters with as many characters as you'd like. So in your scenario all `'³'` chars will be replaced with `ij`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'd better add a `WHERE col LIKE '%³%'`, right?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: No, that will also find rows which contain `3`. That's what OP asks

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oh, that wasn't there when I started answering.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: sure, the _"I get regular 3s as well."_ was there from the beginning. You will not only find rows which contains `3` instead of `³` but also replace those regular `3`.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: now it's working as expected(+1). You could also apply the `COLLATE`-clause to the `WHERE`-clause to restrict also the rows returned.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you, had to do a bit of research before I found the solution.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu you researched my answer!

Comment: @SteveFord I upvoted your answer and actually found similar information elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

This only works if you are using a case sensitive collation, use NCHAR(179) to represent the superscript:

```
create table #t (col1 nvarchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)


INSERT INTO #t
VALUES (NCHAR(179)),('3')

UPDATE #t
    SET col1 = REPLACE(col1, NCHAR(179), 'j')
WHERE col1 like N'%' + NCHAR(179) + N'%'

SELECT *
FROM #t
```

**EDIT
As Radu has pointed out this will work without the table having case sensitive collation:

```
create table #t (col1 nvarchar(50))


INSERT INTO #t
VALUES (NCHAR(179)),('3')

UPDATE #t
    SET col1 = REPLACE(col1, NCHAR(179) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, 'J')
WHERE col1 like N'%' + NCHAR(179) + N'%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

SELECT *
FROM #t
```

Comment: You can solve this even if your data is not collated with `REPLACE(col1, NCHAR(179) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, 'j')`. [**Have a look here**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/386293/496298/).